# How make simple class from xml document?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xsd.exe

xml fragment:

```
...
<invoiceID value=""/> 
<invUNP value=""/> 
<invDateCreate value=""/>
...
```

use xsd get next code

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("invoiceID",Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public getInvoiceReplyInvoiceID[] invoiceID;
public partial class getInvoiceReplyInvoiceID {
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
   public string value;
}
```

this code is not simple

use http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ get c# code

```
...
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "invoiceID")]
public class InvoiceID
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "invUNP")]
public class InvUNP
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
[XmlElement(ElementName = "invoiceID")]
public InvoiceID InvoiceID { get; set; }
[XmlElement(ElementName = "invUNP")]
public InvUNP InvUNP { get; set; }

...
```

how get c# class like next?

```
...
[XmlElement(ElementName = "invoiceID")]
public string InvoiceID { get; set; }
[XmlElement(ElementName = "invUNP")]
public string InvUNP { get; set; }
...
```

may be use svcutil.exe?
or write self parser?

Comment: ...didn't you just write in there...?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is here => [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx)

First parse your xml to xsd the your xsd to .cs

Comment: use xsd get next code
`...                                                                                                              
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("invoiceID",                Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]                       
    public getInvoiceReplyInvoiceID[] invoiceID;                                         
public partial class getInvoiceReplyInvoiceID {                                           
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]                        
    public string value;
}
...`
this code is not simple